# Class not parsing JSON request in retrofit2

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

I'm writing a program to post to a service and using retrofit2 to achieve the same. I have a simple Client class

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(restEndpoint)
    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .build();

proxy = retrofit.create(ServiceAPI.class);
```

RestAPI POST method definition needed to post the JSON.

```
public interface ServiceAPI {
    @POST("api/postAllRequest")
    Call<SampleResponse> postRequest(@Body List<SampleRequest> request);
}
```

Here is the major reason of this question. Following is my SampleRequest class. I wanted to write an abstract class so that it can be extended.

```
public abstract class SampleRequest {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public SampleRequest (String mName, int mAge) {
        this.name = mName;
        this.age = mAge;
    }
}
```

Now the data in SampleRequest gets parsed to JSON correctly but when I extend the SampleRequest class say like below,

```
public class NameRequest extends SampleRequest {
        @Expose
        private String SSN;
        @Expose
        private String DateOfBirth;

        public NameRequest (String mName, int mAge) {
            super(mName, mAge);
        }
    }
```

The resulting JSON is not parsing NameRequest values into the JSON. Can you please advise on this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to private fields, as I see it. Could you please try to add getters and setters to SampleRequest and see, what happen.
I have the same approach in my project, it works and getters/setters is an only difference.

On second thought you can try to change parameters' name in `public SampleRequest (String mName, int mAge)` to "name" and "age". GSON needs exact names to work.

Comment: The problem is not with SampleRequest class but with parsing the fields in NameRequest. I do have getters and setters in my program, just didn't have it above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you declare your service like this :

```
 Call<SampleResponse> postRequest(@Body List<SampleRequest> request);
```

then retrofit assumes that you are sending SampleRequest.

Did you try to declare this service more precisely ? Like in :

```
 Call<SampleResponse> postNameRequest(@Body List<NameRequest > request);
```

Comment: The whole gist of my implementation is to specify the Abstract Class in the SampleRequest and let users extend SampleRequest to parse their Json. So I cannot change the interface code like above.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this could work, because the whole point of the annotation is to generate Java depending on the class you provide... So, afaik, the JSON process will only take the basic fields into account. I'm afraid that you're in a dead-end... :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution, the problem was with the `addConverterFactory` I was using. Once I changed the retrofit2 client to use `GsonConverterFactory`, the json message was getting parsed with the values from the extended class.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(restEndpoint)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .build();
```